# Am I over-nesting in JavaScript Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, nested-if

I am developing a React App (This is not important, because what I am going to explain can happen in other situations as well.)

I have three asynchronous functions, let's call them `func1` and `func2`, and `func3` and this is how they look. This is the general pattern of these functions.

```js
const func1 = async ()=>{
    try {
        // do something
        const resultForFunc2 = // the end result of doing something that is going to be used in func2
        return {statusCode: 200, body: resultForFunc2, error: null}
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error in executing func1", err)
        return {statusCode: 400, body: null, error: err}
    }
}
```

Now the way these functions are called is that `func1` returns a value that is used in `func2` and `func2` returns a value that is used in `func3`.

So this is how I call them:

```js
const all = async () => {
  const response1 = await func1();
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      const response2 = await func2(response1);
      if (response2.statusCode === 200) {
          const response3 = await func3(response2);
          if (response3.statusCode === 200) {
              return { statusCode: 200, body: response3.body, error: null };
          } else {
              return { statusCode: 400, error: response3.error, body: null };
          }
      } else {
        return { statusCode: 400, error: response2.error, body: null };
      } 
  } else {
      return { statusCode: 400, error: response.error, body: null };
  }
}
```

This works for me because I call the above `all` function in a React component, in a  `useEffect()` for example, and whenever I get a 400 `statusCode` I set an error state variable to `true` and then display an error screen (I came up with this idea, so feel free to criticize it, I appreciate it actually). But the bad thing is that I have so many nested `if`s that make the code ugly, dirty, and hard to read and debug. Does anyone have an idea how I can get the benefits of the above code block, without using nested `if`s. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have control over the API? This sounds like an X-Y problem, making 4 requests to get the required information sounds like a broken implementation in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

I have two ideas for reducing nesting. One is using a catch function instead of try catch blocks, i.e.

```js
const err = e => console.error(e);

const func1 = async () => {
    // do something
    const resultForFunc2 = // the end result of doing something that is going to be used in func2
    return {statusCode: 200, body: resultForFunc2, error: null}
}

const result1 = await func1.catch(err);
```

Another idea is to exit on a fail instead of nest the continuing code inside a block. i.e.

```js
const all = async () => {
  const response1 = await func1().catch(err);
  if (response.statusCode !== 200) return { statusCode: 400, error: response.error, body: null };
  const response2 = await func2().catch(err);
  if (response2.statusCode !== 200) return { statusCode: 400, error: response2.error, body: null };
  //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this approach. I did not test it, but i guess it should help you

```
const all = async () => {
  let funcs = [func1, func2, func3];
  let res;
  for (const f of funcs) {
    let { statusCode, body, error } = await f();
    if (statusCode !== 200) return { statusCode, error };
    res = body;
  }
  return res;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I have edited my question. I feel this approach does not work if functions take the output of the previous function as an input.